# MySQL SELECT IN with positional placeholder selects/filters only based on the first value in a string

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

Want to select MySQL rows where column value is 11 or 12 or 23. Tried with such code

```
$query_select_all = 'SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE CAST(EntryId AS UNSIGNED) IN (?)';
$sql = $db->prepare($query_select_all);
$data1[] = '11, 12, 23';
$sql->execute($data1);
```

But the code select only rows where column value is 11 (the first value from `$data1[] = '11, 12, 23';`)

Tried without `?` and works as necessary.

Here is statement without `?` (positional placeholder)

```
$query_select_all = 'SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE CAST(EntryId AS UNSIGNED) IN (11, 12, 23)';
$sql->execute();
```

The statement works as expected (select rows where `EntryId` is 11 or `EntryId` is 12 or `EntryId` is 23.

Where is error in the first code (with `?`)?

Comment: [How can I create a prepared statement for IN () operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991146/285587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991146/285587

```
$query_select_all = 'SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE CAST(EntryId AS UNSIGNED) IN';
$data1 = '11, 12, 23';
$data1 = explode(",",$data1);//Convert Comma Separated String into Array
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($data1) - 1) . '?';
$query_select_all = $query_select_all .'('. $in .')';
$sql = $db->prepare($query_select_all);
$sql->execute($data1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you change the statement with between instead of IN ....

Comment: What if `$query_select_all = 'SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE CAST(EntryId AS UNSIGNED) IN (11, 12,23)';`? I need many `OR` and not `Between`. I will edit my question.